# PHP framework for note taking tool

Tags: php, web, frameworks

Is there any PHP framework that can be used to build online notes taking tool. like Spring pad. So, that i can install in local server and access it.

Comment: Any PHP framework can do this, but which you choose is a matter of preference. Zend, Symfony, Cake, Laravel - try two or three and see what you get on with.

Comment: No, I just want to create one notes taking tool with very basic functionalities like adding notes, deleting notes, Viewing by date etc. Simply like this http://www.springpad.com

Comment: I don't know what further advice you are after. Without doubt, you can do this in any framework. (Nice presentation on that link, though! `:)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is to make a Online Notes Taking Tool.

This could be done in any Framework.

Look at CakePHP, CodeIgniter or any frameworks.

You need to be very specific as to what are you looking at.

Moreover, there is nothing specific that only one Framework could achieve.

Comment: No, I just want to create one notes taking tool with very basic functionalities like adding notes, deleting notes, Viewing by date etc. Simply like this https://springpad.com

Comment: Thats what i said. Any Framework could do this